# How to do a responsive image design

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code to display an image on the desktop.

```
<div class="medium-5 large-12 columns">
  <img style="padding-top: 20px;padding-left:30px" src="~/assets/img/ty-desktop.png" alt="Back" />      
</div>
```

I have different images which need to be displayed when the same webpage is viewed in iPad to this `<div>`.

How can I do that?

I tried to change `class = "medium- 4"` but the image is not resizing it and losing pixels. So I have created new image for iPad and I need to load that image.

Comment: It'd be easier to help you, if you actually post your code..

Comment: those clases 'medium-5', 'large-12', what do they stand for? post code if possible

Comment: Medium-5  and large-12 are bootstrap columns. This is responsive design

Comment: it is not responsive when you display the same file on every resolution, you need to assign different files for different resolutions

Comment: If these were bootstrap classes, they would be `col-md-5` and `col-lg-12`. But since tha classnames doesn't match and you didn't said in the question that you are using bootstrap, we need to check the original code.

Comment: you also have srcset attribute : https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is simply to hide the ipad image by default, and enable it with the media query you want to target the ipad device.

Here's a resource for media queries for various devices/orientations. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

```css
.iPad {
  display: none;
}

/* replace with media query for ipad */
@media (max-width:800px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .iPad {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="medium-5 large-12 columns">
  <img style="padding-top: 20px;padding-left:30px" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" alt="Back" class="desktop" /> 
  <img style="padding-top: 20px;padding-left:30px" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" alt="Back" class="desktop iPad"/>
</div>
```

Comment: such an overkill solution for an easy problem covered natively in html5, but is correct. Only for image it is overkill, but you can use it for some more complex structures

Comment: @EduardVoid agreed. Just another way of doing it.

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 650px)"
    srcset="images/kitten-stretching.png">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 465px)"
    srcset="images/kitten-sitting.png">
  <img 
    src="images/kitten-curled.png" 
    alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I have implemented this in other page of mine.